How to generate a table with a list of possible entries, rather than the count?
Suppose I have a dataframe:
> df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:10,
    name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny",
      "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"),
    gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
      "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"))

I don't want the standard output for this:
> df
   id   name gender
1   1    Bob   Male
2   2 Ashley Female
3   3  James   Male
4   4  David   Male
5   5  Jenny Female
6   6   Hans   Male
7   7    Leo   Male
8   8   John   Male
9   9  Emily Female
10 10    Lee Female

Instead, I want to know which names go with female and which with male:



Female
Male




Ashley
Bob


Jenny
James


Emily
David


Lee
Hans



Leo



John



There are plenty of functions that return the count of each (how many males, or how many James), but I've been unable to figure out how to just get the possible combinations.

Apparently you want this
> split(df$name, df$gender) |> lapply(`length<-`, max(table(df$gender))) |> as.data.frame()
  Female  Male
1 Ashley   Bob
2  Jenny James
3  Emily David
4    Lee  Hans
5   <NA>   Leo
6   <NA>  John

Based on your comment, here a small example with 10 groups instead of only 2:
> set.seed(42)
> df <- data.frame(name=LETTERS, group=sample.int(10, 26, replace=TRUE))
> split(df$name, df$group) |> lapply(`length<-`, max(table(df$group))) |> as.data.frame()
    X1   X2   X3 X4   X5   X7   X8   X9  X10
1    A    G    R  F    B    K    J    D    E
2    C    Q <NA>  L    N <NA>    Z    M    H
3    I    Y <NA>  O    V <NA> <NA>    S    P
4 <NA> <NA> <NA>  U    W <NA> <NA>    T <NA>
5 <NA> <NA> <NA>  X <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

Also possible:
> split(df, ~gender) |> lapply(`[`, 'name')
$Female
     name
2  Ashley
5   Jenny
9   Emily
10    Lee

$Male
   name
1   Bob
3 James
4 David
6  Hans
7   Leo
8  John

maybe you want consider
> split(df$name, df$gender)
$Female
[1] "Ashley" "Jenny"  "Emily"  "Lee"   

$Male
[1] "Bob"   "James" "David" "Hans"  "Leo"   "John" 

or
> split(df$name, df$gender) |> lapply(sort)
$Female
[1] "Ashley" "Emily"  "Jenny"  "Lee"   

$Male
[1] "Bob"   "David" "Hans"  "James" "John"  "Leo"  


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:10, name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", 
"David", "Jenny", "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), gender = c("Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


That gets me close, but 1) I have 23 different gender-type categories, 2) some categories have more than 15 entries, and 3) a table with everything would be much more readable.

@eBerm First solution should work with any number of group levels.

That got it, and I think I understand what the code does. For an extra degree of difficulty, I want to alphabetically sort the names and eventually realized that I needed to arrange() the table prior to splitting.

@eBerm Include sort in another lapply, split(df$name, df$gender) |> lapply(sort) |> lapply(length<-, max(table(df$gender))) |> as.data.frame(). The lapply applies a function to each column, at the end we need as.data.frame to regain data.frame structure.

One approach to consider is tidyr pivot_wider.
This should return a dataframe with Male and Female columns:
library(tidyr)
out <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = gender, values_from = name)

out

# A tibble: 10 × 3
      id Male  Female
   <int> <chr> <chr> 
 1     1 Bob   NA    
 2     2 NA    Ashley
 3     3 James NA    
 4     4 David NA    
 5     5 NA    Jenny 
 6     6 Hans  NA    
 7     7 Leo   NA    
 8     8 John  NA    
 9     9 NA    Emily 
10    10 NA    Lee   

Note that NAs will be coerced into the empty fields you can access each column without the NAs by:
out$Female[!is.na(out$Female)]

In case you have duplicate names in the column just wrap the above in unique()
